# Powershell Invoke-cmd to connect remote machine SQL Server with credentials not working

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

Powershell `Invoke-cmd` to connect to SQL Server on a remote machine with credentials is not working.

`Enter-PSSession` command is executed which successfully connects the remote machine.

```
$sqlpassPowershell = ConvertTo-SecureString "sqluserpass" -AsPlainText -Force
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT QUERY" -ServerInstance "sqlinstanename" -User "sqlusername" -Password $sqlpassPowershell
```

Even though the credentials are correct, I get this error:

```
Instance "MachineName" -User "psUser" -Password $sqlpass
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user 'psUser'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "Select query" - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Invoke-Sqlcmd :
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT query" - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
```

I tried

- `Install-Module SqlServer, dbatools, SqlPS`
- Import all modules

I still get the same error.

If I didn't provide any instance and username, password then it works fine.

Any other solution. I need to figure out this thing as soon as possible. Need to move further on this.

Comment: Check the SQL Server errorlog for reason why login fails.

Comment: `$sqlpassPowershell` is a securestring, but I think that `Invoke-Sqlcmd` password parameter accept plain text string, try to replace it with plain text password first...

Comment: what happens when you try "select name from master.sys.databases" as query

Comment: Thx @vonPryz. I check the error log and found that user was not mapped to the database. 
But, unfortunately, error is same and now the error log says the password for the login is incorrect I check the password 3-4 times. Its correct. I can easily logged In with the user/pass in sql server. but not with Powershell from remote machine. Even tried changing the password. but didn't work . I

Comment: @Avshalom: it works. Passed directly the password to the query and it works 
I was converting to secure string which was the problem